# Openpyxl won't save file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

For some reason Openpyxl won't save the the xlsx file at the end of the program.
I am trying to read measurments from a file, each line is a different measurement. I want to take them and write them  to excel as to make using this data later on easier. Everything seems to work, but in the end the data isn't saved, if i create new file where the changes should be saved it will not be created.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='Data_Base.xlsx')
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
BS = []
Signal = []
with open('WifiData2.txt') as f:
 for line in f:
    y = int(line.split('|')[0].split(';')[3])
    x = int(line.split('|')[0].split(';')[2])
    floor = int(x = line.split('|')[0].split(';')[1])
    data = line.split("|")[1].strip()
    measurements = data.split(";")
    for l in measurements:
        raw = l.split(" ")
        BSSID = raw[0]
        signal_strength = raw[1]
        print(signal_strength)
        BS.append(BSSID)
        Signal.append(signal_strength)

    for row_num in range(sheet.max_row):
        num = row_num
        if row_num > 1:
            test_X = int(sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=4).value)
            test_Y = int(sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3).value)
            test_floor = int(sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2).value)
            if (test_X == x and test_Y == y and test_floor == floor):
                nr = nr + 1

    if (nr > 3):
        q = 1

    if (q == 0):

        sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row+1, column = 2, value = floor)
        sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row + 1, column=3, value=x)
        sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row + 1, column=4, value=y)
        sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row + 1, column=2, value=sheet.max_row)
        for element in BS:
            nr = 0
            for col in sheet.max_column:
                if BS[element] == sheet.cell(row=1, column=col).value:
                    sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row + 1, column=col, value=Signal[element])
                    nr = 1
            if (nr == 0):
                sheet.cell(row=1, column=sheet.max_column+1, value=BS[element])
                sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row+1, column=sheet.max_column + 1, value=BS[element])

    Signal.clear()
    BS.clear()
wb.save('Data_Base1.xlsx')
```

What is weird that if i save the workbook earlier it will create the file. Of course it doesnt really work for me since any changes that i want made won't be made. I had similar issue when i tried it with xlrd/wt/utils combo. Does any1 know where the problem is ?

Comment: Are you attempting to save the changes in a new workbook? You are opening `Data_Base.xlsx` and saving to `Data_Base1.xlsx`

Comment: Yes i am. If eveything goes okay i will try to save it in the original file, but i am not at that stage yet. Data_Base.xlsx is filled with context, i.e. deifinition for certains columns and such

Comment: I simplified your code and there were no issues with saving to `Data_Base1.xlsx`. Perhaps try to remove lines and see if a new file is created? Your code would be easier to test if you shared the formatting of `WifiData2.txt`.

Comment: I guess there is an exception raised before `wb.save`, like `Signal.clear()`, as `Signal` is a list object, it doesn't have `clear` method.

Comment: If the save isn't happening then you're probably caught in a loop that never completes. This might be happening because you're recalculating `ws.max_row` a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path instead of relative path will do the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
wb.template = False
```

before

```
wb.save('Filename.xlsx')
```